# NSNumber numberWithInt: is causing memory leak-Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've been working on the leaks in my program today and I understand most of them but this one is throwing me for a loop:

`[startAndEndPoints addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:buttonTag]];`

The Leaks instrument is pointing to this saying that it is 100% of a leak. Can anyone advise?

startAndEndPoints is a NSMutableArray.

Comment: Are you releasing `startAndEndPoints` is some place?

Comment: well startAndEndPoints is pretty much the backbone of what I have got, so no i do not release it until the user leaves the screen, i do however quite frequently removeAllObjects from it though

Comment: As taskinoor suggests, it may be that you are not releasing startAndEndPoints.  So, that brings to question: How are you declaring startAndEndPoints?  I believe it would be helpful to get a larger sample of your code.  Also, run 'Analyze' on your project.  Chances are, you will get a description as to why it's leaking.  buttonTag is also suspect since we don't know where it's coming from.  Perhaps you are initializing buttonTag with a value and never releasing it.

Comment: So you get leak after user leaves the screen or before? `numberWithInt` does not leak. So if you get leak in this line then there is something wrong with `startAndEndPoints`. Please post some more related codes.

Comment: well  i get the leak while the user is on the screen, because they are interacting with it. @jeremy thanks for the analyze suggestion, helped me in some other areas of my app. I gotta keep looking through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you compare your situation to [iphone app NSNumber memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078631/iphone-app-nsnumber-memory-leak) ? Leaks is telling you how the leaked object got created, not where the leak is. You're probably handing this NSNumber object off to someone else later, and that someone else is over-retaining it.